# Android Database Select Query - Does not show all records

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, database, select

Hello I am beginner to android.I want to make a database connection to mssql server in my pc. I found example on the net. 
I think I have something wrong in connection. Because I have two records in my User table. But this code only gives me first record in table.

Here is ConnectionClass.java :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class ConnectionClass {
String ip = "127.0.0.1:1433";
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = "DBAndroid1";
String un = "TestUser";
String password = "123";
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(classs).newInstance();
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO0", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO1", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO2", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ConnectionClass connectionClass;
EditText edtuserid, edtpass;
Button btnlogin;
ProgressBar pbbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    edtuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
    pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DoLogin  doLogin = new DoLogin();
            doLogin.execute("");

        }
    });

}


public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    String userid = edtuserid.getText().toString();
    String password = edtpass.getText().toString();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(isSuccess) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
        else
        {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    String query = "select Username from [User]";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

                    System.out.println("Eleman sayisi: "+ columnCount);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        String lastName = rs.getString("Username");
                        z = "Login successfull";
                        z = z + " " + lastName;
                        isSuccess=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = "Exceptions burda mi "+ ex;
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
}
}
```

I hope you can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two records in table but you are using if(rs.next()) to fetch record which will return only single record. 
Use for loop or while loop to get all records and iterate resultset in  loop.

Comment: Yes you are right but in any way column count gives me one.